# How do I allow my applications settings to be controlled through group policy?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, application-settings, group-policy

Typical case of making a simple application, boss likes it, sysadmin wants to be able to configure it.

I made a simple login helper application to assist my team members with logging into a pile of different websites/tools in the morning. You create a list of sites, enter your most used password, it logs you in (and prompts for a password for sites with a unique one). Gif here: http://i.imgur.com/0HIVbMw.gif

The sysadmin at my facility has requested that I store the list of websites in the registry and make it available for management via Group Policy (So that the list can be pushed to everyone, and limited in some way). I'm going to be honest, I know nothing about Group Policy. I have heard that storing data in teh registry is not always the best option.

How can I make my applications setting and/or data configurable through Group Policy? Do I need to store it all in the registry? What options do I have that can give our sysadmin the control he desires?

Edit: Can a config file be pushed to the profiles of all users that the application can use?

Comment: seems like a decent candidate for a database.  Install a domain-accessible instance of Sql Server (or Sql Server Express), and give your sysop SSMS.  Personally, I'd avoid storing config settings in the registry at (almost) all costs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not knowledgeable about how a database could be accessible or manageable for my Sysop (or really anything SQL), but I will definitely start checking it out. Out of curiosity, can you push files with group policy? If so he could just push a read-only config file to each users appdata folder to enable restrictive settings and define the list of allowable sites.

Edit: Ohhh I get it, SQL server on sever of domain, devices connect to it to get what they need as far as configs and site lists.

Comment: I'm not aware of any "file pushing" capabilities with GPO.   If databases aren't your thing then you could store the settings as an XML or JSON (or whatever format you choose) file on a network share. (make the share readonly for users and read/write for admins)  When you open the file from your code be sure to use the FileStream class and `FileShare.ReadWrite`.

Comment: Databases are definitely not my thing, but I can learn. The config on a network share makes sense. Though I need to make sure it's as low-effort as possible for the sysadmin. Registry + GP seems to be the easiest for him, which is probably why he wanted it. Again, thanks for taking the time to reply, I appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, databases are easy.  And probably something you should know anyhow :)  You can always make a new app for you sysop that hides all the database stuff from him and just lets him edit the config values.